# Jmeter - ${__P(var)} doesn't work during remote (distributed) testing

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I'm using **${__P(users,2)}** to specify **no of threads(users)** at run time

it's working fine when i execute script on single Machine.

But when i Execute same script in Distributed environment it's not working

properly.It takes default value 2 .

I also tried with removing default value  e.g. **${__P(users)}**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass local property via `-J` command line argument like

```
jmeter -Jusers=50
```

If you're running tests in distributed mode you need to substitute it with `-G` switch where you can provide either a single property or .properties file, in this case global properties will be pushed to remote JMeter servers

> ```
>     -J, --jmeterproperty <argument>=<value>
>             Define additional JMeter properties
>     -G, --globalproperty <argument>=<value>
>             Define Global properties (sent to servers)
>             e.g. -Gport=123
>              or -Gglobal.properties**
>     -D, --systemproperty <argument>=<value>
>             Define additional system properties
>     -S, --systemPropertyFile <argument>                                                                                                                                 
>             additional system property file(s)
> ```

See [How do I run JMeter in non-gui mode](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) for more options explained.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to specify global property using ant ?
I'm using ant call as below, it's working fine for runremote="false" but Fail to get value when i try with runremote=''true"  
`<jmeter jmeterhome="D:\Automation\Seleniumtoolkit\Jmeter\apache-`jmeter-2.13" resultlog="../Report/JMeterReport/JMeterResults.jtl" ``runremote="true">`
   `<testplans dir="../JMeter" includes="*.jmx"/>`
   `<property name="USERS" value="5"/>`
   `<property name="SERVER" value="xyz.com"/>`
  ` <property name="INSTANCE" value="Myinstance"/>`
   `<property name="SITE_ID" value="2631"/>`
  `</jmeter>`

Comment: I'm unable to read `-Gfoo=bar` or `--globalproperty foo=bar` set property with `${__P(foo)}` or `${__property(foo,,undefined)}` using JMeter 5.1.1. When I use `-Jfoo=bar` it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables). In this case your variable should be visible for other agents as well.